# Why jquery datapicker inconsistently shows up?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Here is my problem. It seems that datapicker does not show up when clicked the first time on the dynamically added input (I have to click two or more times on it or best if I click above the input (label area)), does anyone see the problem. I tried a lot of live(), bind() .hasDatapicker and #datep1 variants. If possible test your answer first. Thanks.

script side:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var div_data='<div id="div_data" class="data"><br />'+
   'Dates from: <input type="text" id="datep1" size="10" name="data1">'+
   ' to: <input type="text" id="datep2" size="10" name="data2">&nbsp;&nbsp;(Optional fields)</div>'; 
    $("#rod_sem").after(div_data);
    $(".br1").remove();
$(":input[name='pasirink']").click(function(){
    var currentId = $(this).attr("id");
    if (currentId == 'rod_sem')
        {
        $(".br1").remove();
        $(".data").remove(); // this is done to prevent repetitive additions
        $("#rod_sem").after(div_data); // here comes datepicker input

        $("#datep1").live("click", function() {
            $("#datep1").datepicker();
        })

        }

    })
})
</script>
```

Html:

```
<label id="la_rod_sem" for="rod_sem">Seminars</label>
<input type="radio" name="pasirink" id="rod_sem" value="rod_sem" checked="checked" />
<br class="br1" /> 
<br class="br1" />
<label id="la_rod_klaus" for="rod_klaus">Attendees</label>
<input type="radio" name="pasirink" id="rod_klaus" value="rod_klaus" />
<br />
<br />
```

Comment: `live` has been deprecated for quite a while, use `on` instead. Not that that's the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [jQuery LiveQuery plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs):

```
   $("#datep1").livequery("click", function(event) {
        $(this).datepicker();
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this part:

```
$("#datep1").live("click", function() {
        $("#datep1").datepicker();
    })
```

To this:

```
$("#datep1").datepicker();
```

The datepicker plugin is activated when the input is clicked, so you do not have to wrap this in a click event.